# Condition on the dimension of a subspace so that the intersection of the image and the domain is not null

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional subspace. Let $W\subset V$. then what $\textit{necessary and sufficient}$ condition need be given on the dimension of the space $W$ so that $T(W)\cap W\neq \{0\}$ for every linear automorphism $T:V\to V$?

I think this question is asking somewhat related to when a subspace could be invariant under the linear automorphism of the superspace. Typically, should the dimension of $W$ be half of that of $V$ or less more than it?

Comment: Is $W$ a subspace? If so you can never have $T(W) \cap W=\emptyset$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Why does that always happen? You mean the zero of $W$ would be same as zero of $T(W)$?

Comment: Yes,  $0 \in T(W) \cap W$

Comment: @KaboMurphy ok! modified the question

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. a simple example of such a projection?

Comment: Projections other than the identity are not linear automorphisms.

Comment: OK, I read quickly, but now if $T$ is an automorphism, then $dim(T(W))=dim(W)$ and if you want $T(W)\cap W=\{0\}$ then you must have $dim(V)\geq 2 dim(W)$ and the converse is true (think in terms of adapted bases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m:=\dim(W)$ and $n:=\dim(V)$. You'd want $m>\frac{n}{2}$.

**Necessary:** If $m\leq\frac{n}{2}$, then we can consider an automorphism $T:V\to V$ which maps $W$ into its complement $W'$ (i.e. $V=W\oplus W'$) since $\dim(W')=n-m\geq n-\frac{n}{2}\geq m$.

**Sufficient:** If $m>\frac{n}{2}$, take an automorphism $T:V\to V$. Then $T(W)$ is $m$-dimensional so $W\cap T(W)\neq\{0\}$ because otherwise we would have $$\dim(V)\geq \dim(W)+\dim(T(W))=m+m>n.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** For vector subspaces $W, X \subseteq V$, $$\dim (W + X) = \dim W + \dim X - \dim (W \cap X) .$$ What can we say about the relationship between $\dim W, \dim T(W)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is an automorphism, then $dim(T(W))=dim(W)$ and if you want $T(W)\cap W=\{0\}$ then you must have $dim(V)\geq 2 .dim(W)$ and the converse is true. Let's construct this in terms of adapted bases.
Let $dim(W)=k<n=dim(V)$ (the case when dim(W)=0 being trivial) and 
$e_i,\ 1\leq i\leq n$ a basis of $V$ such that the first $k$ are a basis of $W$ (i.e. $e_i,\ 1\leq i\leq k$ is a basis of $W$, of course $0<k<2.k\leq n$) then, the endomorphism defined by $T(e_i)=e_{i+k}$ for $i\leq n-k$ and $T(e_i)=e_{i-k}$ for $i>n-k$ does the job.